# Android: Inheriting a style and setting value of a custom attribute in it is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I have a custom attribute in `attr.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="buttonBackgroundColor" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

I've created a drawable `button_background.xml` which use that custom attribute:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="?buttonBackgroundColor"/>


    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

and I've defined a style like below:

```
<style name="button_background">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">3dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>

    </style>
```

I'm defining value of that custom attribute in these child styles:

```
<style name="button_background_green" parent="button_background">
      <item name="buttonBackgroundColor">@color/Green</item>
</style>

<style name="button_background_blue" parent="button_background">
      <item name="buttonBackgroundColor">@color/Blue</item>
</style>
```

I'm using `button_background_green` stye in a `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/done"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    style="@style/button_background_green"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:text="@string/done" />
```

I think this is how we implement styles which have many common properties but it is not working. If I set `android:background` property to a color in child style, it works perfectly. So I think for some reason it is not able to read `buttonBackgroundColor` attribute. Please help. I would really appreciate it.